# Add links to top links navigation

Tags: layout, frontend, toplinks, certification

I'm studying to get FE certification and I'm trying to add a link to top.links block adding this code to local.xml:

```
<action method="addLink" block="top.links">
            <label>shop</label>
            <url>http://google.com</url>
            <title>test</title>
        </action>
```

Although it works properly, I can't find any reference or example using the "block" parameter inside the "action" tag. Anyone knows which parameters are allowed in the action tag? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can find the answer by looking at `_generateAction` method inside `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` class. You will find following strings:

- ifconfig
- method
- block
- helper
- json

Comment: found it, thanks.Do you know why I can't find any reference about the block parameter in the Magento Design Guide for example?

Comment: By default, the block parameter is not used.  If omitted, the action method will reference the parent block directive.  Adding the "block" parameter will tell the action directive to ignore this and instead use the block you referenced.  It is not referenced because it is not a commonly used parameter.  Action directives are primarily used through node nesting.